# Highcharts highlight a column dynamically

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart of countries. I don't know what position my target country will end up at in the chart - it depends on the data. How to dynamically highlight it, e.g., change the column colour and the name colour? For example if my target country is Portugal, how to display this in a different colour than the others.

https://jsfiddle.net/2vsd7knr/1/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Sweden',
            'South_Korea',
            'Israel',
            'Russia',
            'Canada',
            'Portugal',
            'Turkey',
            'Iran',
            'France',
            'China',
            'Belgium',
            'Brazil'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a guideline how to finds current points and change their color.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bd8xL6m2/

```
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      render() {
        let chart = this,
          x;

        chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
          if (p.category === targetCountry) {
            x = p.x;
            p.graphic.element.style.fill = 'red'
          }
        })

        chart.xAxis[0].ticks[x].label.element.style.fill = 'red'
      }
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render